# Unique identifier for web apps on iis

Tags: iis

When I add a new web application in IIS, is there any unique identifier created for that application? And by unique I mean that if the application is deleted and a new one is added, the new one won't take the old app's ID.

Comment: Could you describe why you want such a unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from IIS7 a Website or WebApplication is configured inside the `applicationHost.config` file located in the `C:\Window\System32\inetsrv\config\ directory.

If you browse the `<site>` section configuration here : http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site  you can see that there is only one `id` which is unique in IIS but no globally unique.

Unfortunately there is no unique identifier for the website.